# SQL file contents appear empty in Azure Devops when reviewing PR or browsing repo even though they're not

Tags: git, azure-devops

Encountered a very perplexing problem.

My files show up as having no contents both in a PR and while browsing the repo.

However, when I view commits and [click on the *folder* it shows up correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHi0v.png)

[If I click on the file itself, it shows no content.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytirP.png)

It only happens with a few specific files. Deleting these files, pushing, then creating them anew and pushing does not solve the problem.

Re-naming them doesn't make a difference. Nor does re-naming the parent directory.

Created a new branch from the master branch and re-created the same files manually, still same issue.

Pulling this branch works correctly and the files show up as they're supposed to. [Downloading the file contents from Devops also gets the correct file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uypt.png)

The files look to be UTF-8 when viewed in VSCode and Sublime, and ASCII when using "file"-command in Bash. They don't seem different in any way from other files in the repo, which are displayed as expected.

Now in theory the PR can still be reviewed by looking at the commit history or looking at the branch locally.

However I would really like to find the cause of this issue so it doesn't risk spreading.

I would expect that it could be a bug in Devops, which feels unlikely since I have spent hours googling without finding any reports. Other than that, it might be an encoding issue.

The tools I'm using are WSL Ubuntu, VSCode and Git CLI. All files have been created in that environment, not copied from any Windows filesystem.

I would be very appreciative of any suggestions. Apologies for not being able to insert images inline (my post score is too low), all links lead to imgur.

Comment: Does the empty and not empty file size have a difference? I tried to test the issue but it is fine in my side. Please try to view the network trace by clicking F12 to open the Develop tools, and see if there is any error message in it. You can compare the network trace when opening the files that seems empty and not empty to find the difference.

Comment: Thank you very much. The cause is that I'm building an integration for Google Ads and uBlock origin blocked out the file containing "google ads" in its name.

Quite a silly issue to get stumped by but I'm very thankful you could help me solve it.

Comment: Please answer the question if you'd like and I can accept your answer and mark this as solved.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found the cause :) I have posted it in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to view the network trace by clicking F12 to open the Develop tools, and see if there is any error message in it. You can compare the network trace when opening the files that seems empty and not empty to find the difference.

Then you found the cause is that you are building an integration for Google Ads and uBlock origin blocked out the file containing "google ads" in its name.

Comment: What the heck? AdBlock was preventing this from working properly! SO weird.

Comment: I had the same issue, and in my case the typescript file contains some Matomo package usage that is known by Adblock as a tracking system. While it's kind of rude, it makes totally sense.